# More easily identify css selectors in R Shiny Apps

Tags: css, r, shiny

I"m building a few Shiny apps, and I've opted to do a totally custom css style sheet (instead of using a predefined template).

I'm spending way too much time trial-and-erroring my way through the css stylesheet, trying to identify which selectors control which aspect of the Shiny app.

I've learned to use Google Chrome's inspect functionality to look at the background code but still don't know what copy/adapt.

Can someone point me into the right direction with workflows related to css and Shiny in R?

Thanks

Comment: [`bootstraplib`](https://rstudio.github.io/bootstraplib/) could be a great solution to simplify Shiny apps designing, but I think it is not finished yet. You could also simplify your `.css` files by creating `.scss` files instead, which are based on SASS. There is an R package to convert `.scss` files to `.css` files. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/sass/articles/sass.html) for more info. Both of these approaches are detailed [here](https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/styling-shiny-apps-with-sass-and-bootstrap-4/). Otherwise, I guess it just takes time to use CSS effectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but as you are creating your shiny apps, you can wrap each object in a div and give each object a class.  That way rather than fighting with a predefined style, you can code css only for the objects you want via your defined classes.

For example, you can wrap a datatable in class = 'table' and manipulate the components of the table and even create a 'box' around it using borders, shadow and border-radius.

r:

```
tags$div(class = 'table', DT::dataTableOutput(ns("your_table")))
```

css:

```
.table{
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2), inset 0 5px 0 var(--tab_color);
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: var(--bg-border);
background-color: var(--bg-dark);

padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```